# List index out of range error only occurs when scraping online

Tags: python, selenium

Using bs4 to grab text from four td tags.  Code works perfectly on downloaded html from the actual page, but throws 'list index out of range' error when run on identical page online.

Here is the relevant HTML, the code snipped is below.

```
<tr>    
        <td class="tdtitle" style="width:162px;">
            Number:
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_caseSummary_lblCaseNumber" class="summaryTextBox">[Case Number]</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdtitle" style="width:162px;">
            Status:
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_caseSummary_lblCaseStatus" class="summaryTextBoxAlt">CASE OPEN</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdtitle" style="width:162px;">
            Judge Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_caseSummary_lblJudgeName" class="summaryTextBox">[JUDGE NAME]</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Attempted to sleep a few seconds before executing to insure page is loaded for bs4 soup object to grab it all.  Error persists
Tested code on other versions of the same content, another case, same error online, same successful data recovery when using offline html code.  Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
data_sites = [8, 27, 12, 10]
    data_list = []
    for locations in data_sites:
        case_data = summ_soup.find_all('td')[locations]
        data_list.append(case_data.text)
```

Expected result with the text of the four td tags as numbered in the data_sites list. i.e.

```
data_list = ['<CASE NUMBER>', 'CASE OPEN', 'JUDGE NAME', '<statute content>'].
```

I get the above accurate result when testing code on the downloaded complete html page.  Did that to avoid repeatedly hitting website while designing the code.  Tested this on several different cases, i.e. the text content is in a template and always appears at the same td tag.

However, when running the code online, I keep receiving this error.

```
File "<path to my python file>", line 145, in get_summ_data
    case_data = summ_soup.find_all('td')[locations]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Using Python 3.7 and Pycharm if that matters at all.  Also, ran code online while connect via a VPN.

Comment: Are the tables that you're parsing of the same size ?

Comment: When you ask about size, do you mean, the same number of rows, columns?  From my testing, they have the same number of rows with the identical data contained in each row which resulted in perfect results when testing the complete HTML offline, but results in this error when hitting the same html online.

Comment: The way you are using find_all and access the data can easily lead to this error whenever something unexpected happens and you do not get as many result elements as you expect. Better call find_all only once and check for its size before looping and accessing the values with [locations]

Comment: There's a good chance that the offline HTML source is not exactly the same as the online one and you're dealing with other scales of the table. By the way, do you make sure that you're dealing with the table that you want to work with ? Meaning, look for the table and then parse its 'td'

Comment: First of all, is this a dynamic table. Does the table will show the data right after loading the page when running in headless mode?

Comment: @supputuri I have not run this in headless mode, but otherwise, the table is not dynamic, I don't think.  It is a template into which the same data types are placed gathered from a database on their end I presume.

Comment: @MosheS. I cannot locate table names for these tables.  Did figure out how to count the number of td tags and tables, but getting the precise table here, still working on that.

Comment: @Janine Thanks for your quick reply.  Working on changing the code to see if that works more smoothly.